# How to reduce a stream of double properties with add?

Tags: javafx, properties, javafx-8

Given I have a stream or list of double properties that should all be bind together with the add operation, **what is the right way to do this in JavaFX?**

The following doesn't work since `DoubleExpression::add` returns a `DoubleBinding` instead of a `DoubleProperty`.

```
DoubleBinding value = doubleProperties.stream()
    .reduce(doubleProperty, doubleProperty2) -> doubleProperty.add(doubleProperty2)).get();

DoubleBinding value = doubleProperties.stream()
    .reduce(DoubleExpression::add).get();
```

The following works but is a hack that I don't think should be necessary:

```
DoubleBinding value = doubleProperties.stream()
                .map(doubleProperty -> doubleProperty.add(0))
                .reduce(DoubleExpression::add)
                .get();
```

Comment: If you don't mind ending up with a `NumberBinding` instead, you can do `doubleProperties.stream().map(NumberBinding.class::cast).reduce(Bindings::add).get()`

Answer (score 0):

The most use able solution for me is using DoubleExpression instead of DoubleProperty or DoubleBinding.

```
DoubleExpression value = doubleProperties.stream()
                .map(DoubleProperty::doubleExpression)
                .reduce(DoubleExpression::add)
                .get();
```

I don't actually understand the nuances between these three classes.
If someone knows if this construct does what I probably expect and what the differences are, please feel free to comment or answer.